# How do spore showers work?

Tags: commonwealth-saga

People take "*spore showers*" in Peter F. Hamilton's [Void Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Trilogy) quite often.

How exactly do they work?

Comment: Judging purely on their name, I don’t think I want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spore Showers seem to work like conventional showers but instead of water, they dispense dry spores held in a powder. The user rubs themselves with them, then uses jets of air blow them off.

> *"Her u-shadow told her when it was eleven o’clock, which barely gave
>   her enough time for a spore shower in the fourth apartment where she
>   was living. **Two of the old shower’s five nozzles weren’t working**,
>   and one of the remaining jets smelt funny"*

The spores are described as being "squirted" from the fixtures:

> *After the shower had squirted dermal fresher spores over him, he walked through into the vast lounge, bronze sunlight washing warmly across his tingling skin.*

The spores cause:

> *a slight tingle on the skin*

The spores come out of the nozzles at differing temperatures, at the control of the user:

> *So he turned the spore temperature down about as low as it would go,
>   and thought of other things.*

The spores seems to be dry, rather than held in suspension:

> *Then there was a shower—none of that modern itchy spore crap that
>   clogged up his hair but a proper hot water and scented gel affair.*

The spores can be used in conjunction with water or on their own:

> *“Good.” He stretched and rolled his shoulders. “Give me a shower,” he
>   told the smartcore. “Start with water; shift to spores when I tell
>   you.” ... After the spores cleaned and dried his skin he dressed in a
>   simple dark purple one-piece suit*

The spores themselves may be a derivative of the waxy 'sporecones' seen in the second book in the series;

> *They made camp that third day under overhanging branches which dripped
>   an unpleasant waxy sap from their **newly budded scarlet sporecones**.*

---

Overall the concept seems to be extremely similar to the "powder shower" seen in the film [Tank Girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank_Girl_(film)), albeit with an active (biological) cleaning agent rather than merely using abrasive dust.

Comment: Sounds to me like they'd work like a combination of *dry shampoo* and sand (which you can also use to clean yourself depending on the kind of dirt to get off).

Comment: @mario - Yes, but with some kind of active biological component...